# Replace sub string with number of it's occurrences

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to replace a sub string with the number of it's occurrences for example:

```
$text = "The dog is saying wooff wooff wooff wooff but he should say 
bark bark bark bark not wooff wooff wooff";

$newText = preg_replace('!\wooff+', 'wooff{$total}', $text);
```

the result should be :

```
$newText = "The dog is saying wooff4 but he should say 
bark bark bark bark not wooff3";
```

Comment: Ok, so is there a problem with that code? Does it generate errors? Does it generate any output? In short what is the problem

Comment: What would `woof woof bark woof` look like?

Comment: @RiggsFolly plase check the update, I am not sure if preg_replace have some callback functionality to show the preg replaced words as I described.

Comment: @AbraCadaver please check the update again

Comment: @LuBlue No update?

Comment: @vivek_23 that is exactly what I was thinking of :D ! Great Job mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$text = "The dog is saying wooff wooff wooff wooff but he should say bark bark bark bark not wooff wooff wooff";

$newText = preg_replace_callback('|([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\s\1)*|',function($matches){
                $same_strings = explode(" ",$matches[0]);
                return $same_strings[0] . count($same_strings);
            },$text);


echo "Old String: ",$text,"<br/>";
echo "New String: ",$newText;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Old String: The dog is saying wooff wooff wooff wooff but he should say bark bark bark bark not wooff wooff wooff
New String: The1 dog1 is1 saying1 wooff4 but1 he1 should1 say1 bark4 not1 wooff3
```

If you don't wish to catch for words that occur only once, you can modify callback function as below-

```
<?php

$text = "The dog is saying wooff wooff wooff wooff but he should say bark bark bark bark not wooff wooff wooff";

$newText = preg_replace_callback('|([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\s\1)*|',function($matches){
                $same_strings = explode(" ",$matches[0]);
                if(count($same_strings) === 1){
                    return $matches[0];
                }
                return $same_strings[0] . count($same_strings);
            },$text);


echo "Old String: ",$text,"<br/>";
echo "New String: ",$newText;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Old String: The dog is saying wooff wooff wooff wooff but he should say bark bark bark bark not wooff wooff wooff
New String: The dog is saying wooff4 but he should say bark4 not wooff3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this using [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and a `foreach`.
Getting started:

```
// Your string and the word you are searching
$str = "The dog is saying wooff wooff wooff wooff but he should say bark bark bark bark not wooff wooff wooff";
$search = 'wooff';
```

Now the replacement:

```
// Get the duplicates
preg_match_all('/(' . $search . '[\s]?){2,}/', $str, $duplicates);

// Foreach duplicates, replace them with the number of occurence of the search word in themselves
$new_str = $str;
foreach ($duplicates[0] as $dup) {
    $count = substr_count($dup, $search);
    $new_str = str_replace($dup, $search . $count . ' ', $new_str);
}
$new_str = trim($new_str);
```

Output:

```
echo $new_str;
// The dog is saying wooff4 but he should say bark bark bark bark not wooff3
```